# Computing curvature of vector fucntion

Tags: calculus, vectors

I have the following question

given r(t) =  e^(t) cos(t) i + e^(t) sin(t) j, where 0 < t < infinity

reparametrize the curve by arc length and compute its curvature.

I know how to reparametrise it but can't seem to use the reparametrisation to computer curvature.

Help

Comment: Do you know the formula for the curvature?

Comment: Yes. But I think I am supposed to use the reparametrized version.